# Help me visualize a function with infinitely many logarithms of absolute values of logarithms

Tags: recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions, math-software, visualization

> Where and how can I plot something like this:
>
> $$f(x)=\log(|\log(|\log(|\underbrace{\dots}_{n}\log(|x|)|)|)|)$$
>
> Where $n\to\infty$? What would happen to the function?

---

I would thank both answers so far ([Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327490) and [Joonas Ilmavirta](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327746)), and just add in the question the graphs for $n=1\dots9$ produced with [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42723/paul)s comment in the first answer:

[image]

Where we see that most of the plot will get covered with values that diverge, and countably many initial points that do converge, will converge to $-W(1)\approx-0.567143290409783872999968662\dots$ , where $W$ is the [Lambert W Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make sense of this, we might define $f_0(x)=x$, $f_{n+1}(x)=\ln(|f_n(x)|)$, and finally $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$.
If this should converege for any $x$ at all then certainly to a number $y$ with the property $y=\ln(|y|)$, i.e., $e^y=|y|$. This has only one solution $\approx -0.5671432904$, so that $f$ has to be constant (where it converges).
However, $f$ often fails to converge, for example if we reach $0$ after finitely many iterations.

Comment: I see it now thanks, but do you know of any way (using a software) to plot this, possibly with a slider for $n$ to visualize what happens to the plot of the function as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Vepir I like to use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) for this. To plot $f_n$ and have a slider to set $n$ you can use this code: `Manipulate[Plot[Nest[Log[Abs[#]]&, x, n], {x, -10, 10}], {n, 0, 20, 1}]`

Comment: @Paul Thanks! Btw, I don't know why their page is misleading and it seems like you need to register and download a trial, just to run some simple code, when they have [Wolfram Lab](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), where at the bottom left one can click "Create a New Notebook" and run some lines of code such as you provided, without needing to register or anything at all. Just leaving this here if someone reads this in the future and is not familiar with Mathematica, since when I found Mathematica for the first time, I wasn't aware of the wolfram lab online.

Comment: @Vepir That's useful, I didn't know about Wolfram Lab

Comment: In fact, the sequence only converges for countably many initial points. I gave the details in an answer.

Comment: @Paul For anyone interested, one can quickly create a notebook following this link (no registration required... but needed if you want to save): https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/

Answer (score 10):

Writing $g(x)=\log(|x|)$, you are looking at the iterates of the function $g$.
The only possible limit, as Hagen von Eitzen points out, is the only fixed point of $g$, namely $a\approx-0.57$.

A fixed point is called stable if for $x$ close enough to $a$ iterating $g$ brings $x$ closer and closer to $a$.
The stability of the fixed point at $a$ is related to the value of $|g'(a)|$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Stability_of_fixed_points).
Since $|g'(a)|\approx1/0.57>1$, the fixed point is exponentially unstable: any point $x$ close to but not exactly at $a$ moves further away from it at exponential rate.

Therefore the only way a sequence $(x_i)$ given by $x_{i+1}=g(x)$ can converge to $a$ is that $x_N=a$ for some $N$.
That is, you have to hit the limit exactly after a finite number of iterations.
There are only countably many starting points $x_0\in\mathbb R$ that satisfy this; otherwise there is no limit.

The absolute value of the derivative of $x\mapsto\log(|x|)$ is $\approx1/0.57>1$ at the fixed point, so the fixed point is unstable. Therefore convergence to the limit is very rare even if you avoid zero: you have to hit the fixed point after finitely many iterations.
It is possible to write the set of all such initial points recursively, but I'm not sure if that gives any additional insight.

Also only countably many initial points lead you to zero so that the sequence terminates and the definition doesn't make sense.
For most real numbers (cocountably many) the iterates of $g$ are well defined but don't converge.

**Conclusion:**
The limit function is only defined in countably many points and takes the same value $a$ at every such point.

Comment: "The limit function is only defined in finitely many points" - Shouldn't that be countably infinite?

Comment: @Paul Yes, it should. Good catch, thanks! Edited.